# Does any mechanism of action exist that would allow topical application of jojoba oil to down-regulate sebum production?

Tags: dermatology, research

[This](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23473858/) study found that adapalene (brand name Differin) suppresses "TG and PLIN1 production in differentiated hamster sebocytes" leading to the stated goal of "an inhibitory action for sebum accumulation." Thus, some mechanism of action exists to down-regulate sebum production via topical applications.

Secondarily, [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-43209-3) study found that "down-regulation of TFG decreased lipid production."

[Jojoba oil's chemical makeup is remarkably similar to sebum](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19134124/).

[This study shows that lipid production can be down-regulated via topical application of jojoba oil](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6780807/).

"As a result, after 30 min of topical application of jojoba oil, FABPpm, FATP-1, FATP-3, and FATP-4 tended to be downregulated in the skin."

"[A] trend of decreasing fatty acid trafficking-related gene (FABPpm, FATP-1, FATP-3, and FATP-4) expression in the skin after topical application of jojoba oil (p = 0.067, 0.074, 0.076, and 0.082, respectively) was observed."

In reference to a comment posted here: excess sebum production on the face through natural accumulation shouldn't hypothetically cause down-regulation of sebum. But exogenous application of sebum might.

And being that jojoba oil might be similar to exogenous application of sebum given the chemical composition, this could cause down-regulation of natural sebum production.

Similar to how individuals with testosterone in the high end (potentially excess) of the reference range does not cause down-regulation, but exogenous testosterone does.

Comment: Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please edit your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Specifically, you might ask yourself, if there is such a mechanism why excess sebum buildup doesn't trigger it?

Comment: @CareyGregory I'm actually very grateful for the comments. It's caused me to read for the past hour and a half on these studies, and I've learned a lot. I'm very new to research, this website, and asking scientific questions. 

I attempted to add clarification. Hopefully it suffices, but I suspect it has unnecessary information, but I wanted to explain my thought process.

Comment: [1] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6780807/ [2] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2835893/

These two studies are likely keys in understanding its effect. But I'm not understanding the outcomes of [1] in relation to [2].

Comment: You're headed in exactly the right direction. I think you should add the first article you linked to in your comment above to the question along with a relevant quote from the abstract.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks, I'll edit the question tomorrow. Appreciate all the help.

Comment: *"I suspect it has unnecessary information, but I wanted to explain my thought process"* - Thought processes help answerers to formulate a more useful answer and so it is good to put them out there in the question, especially when backed by cited research. Cited research also helps others to learn while waiting for an answer, so also a double whammy of usefulness of the question. I'm glad the comments helped. Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE

Comment: @CareyGregory I think the formatting is poor, but not sure what the standard is. I do believe this impact on lipid metabolism is key in understanding the question. I added some information from the study, which showed a down-regulation of certain lipids. If the formatting is poor, feel free to tell me how to correct it, or you can edit it to fit the standard.

Again, thank you very much for all of the help.

Comment: The format's fine. We're more interested in content than style.